# Error when trying to set the subform recordsource to an sql query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to change the recordset of a subform to display the query result

So I have a string query :

```
sQueryCurrencyRate = "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date =" & Format(dateField.value, "M/d/yyyy")


 sQueryCurrencyUsDollar = "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date =" & Format(dateField.value, "M/d/yyyy")
```

So when I write this , the subform display a result without error :

```
 Me.subformName.Form.RecordsourceSourceObject = "Table.tableName"
```

but When I try all of the below I always receive an error :

```
Forms!formName.subformName.Form.RecordSource= sQueryCurrencyRate
```

I have also tried :

```
Me.subFormName.Form.RecordsourceSourceObject= sQueryCurrencyRate
```

Also ,

```
 Me.subFormName.RecordsourceSourceObject= sQueryCurrencyRate
```

No matter what I do , I always end up having this error message :

> the expression you have entered refers to an object that is closed or
>   doesn't exist

What I'm doing wrong? and how to properly display the query result in the subform recordsource ?

P.S: the sql queries syntax are fine because I have previously tested them with :

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sQueryCurrencyRate)
```

and I received no error , so the problem is how to bind the subform result to the query

EDIT:

The way I'm calling the code is like below :

```
Function detectSelectedQuery(sTypeDonnee As String)

sQueryCurrencyRate = "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date = ' " & Format(dateField.value, "M/d/yyyy") &"'"

 Me![Child8].Form.RecordSource = sQueryCurrencyRate
end function
```

then when the combobox is changed I call the function :

```
Private Sub Combo_descriptionQueries_Change()
detectSelectedQuery (Combo_descriptionQueries.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I did also tried simply doing 'me.subformName.Form.RecordSource= sQueryCurrencyRate' and 'me.subformName.RecordSource= sQueryCurrencyRate' without any success , It's weird

Comment: Where are you calling this code? On the main form?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have declared a function called Execute Query and inside of it , I'm calling the code

Comment: How exactly are you calling this? If you call it, is the form open or closed?

Comment: Please provide the **full** code block (event trigger) that runs the process, not line snippets.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth see my edited question

Comment: Not familiar with Access, but shouldn't `RecordSourceObject` be a `Recordset` instance and therefore be `Set`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug the whole `RecordSetObject` part is wrong, he intends to set `RecordSource`, which is a string SQL statement that the form uses (there also is a `RecordSet` property, but that shouldn't be changed unless you want to use an ADO recordset as recordsource)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I get your point. When using Access as a backend too, security is usually a moot point since users need to have write access on the database file, but when using a proper backend, an ADODB recordset is certainly preferred

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth it's not *just* about security, it's also about correctness. You want `Kenneth O'Connor` to be able to fill up that `LastName` field without wrecking the front-end. Let alone `Robert '); DROP TABLE Students;--` ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I fully agree, I was working on an own answer in the meantime. Unfortunately, the proper way to do it is not as concise as the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this properly (without any risk of SQL injection), you can use an ADODB recordset:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE As_Of_Date = @MyDate"
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cmd.Parameters("@MyDate") = cmd.CreateParameter("MyDate", adDate)
cmd.Parameters("@MyDate").Value = datefield.Value
Set Me.Recordset = cmd.Execute
```

Note that this requires a reference to the ActiveX Data Objects library

Comment: I think the `cmd.Parameters("@MyDate")` assignment should be `Set`, since `CreateParameter` returns an `ADODB.Parameter` object reference. Might work regardless if the property mutator's value receives a `Variant`, which would hold the pointer to the object reference. Also I think you can drop the `rs` local variable and `Set Me.Recordset = cmd.Execute`

Comment: @Mat'sMug You're right about that second one, but the first one (changing the `cmd.Parameters` assignment to a `Set` results in a compile error (invalid use of property) for me. Don't know why, but it works without and doesn't work with the `Set`

Comment: Interesting. I usually do `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
sQueryCurrencyRate = "SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE As_Of_Date = #" & Format(dateField.value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

To avoid concatenating, you could use TempVars or create a small helper function:

```
' Public variable:
Dim FilterDate As Date

Public Function GetFilterDate() As Date
    GetFilterDate = FilterDate
End Function
```

and then an extra line of code:

```
FilterDate = Me!dateField.Value
sQueryCurrencyRate = "SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE As_Of_Date = GetFilterDate()"
```

Comment: Kudos for proper *date literal* delimiters... is there not a way to avoid string-concatenation though?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in Access, why not use the default DAO interface with a parameter query instead of ADODB? No need for an ActiveX Data Objects reference.

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

'For an existing query
Set qdf = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qryName")

'To create query (Credit to @Erik von Asmuth for pointing this out)
Set qdf = CurrentDb().CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS [@MyDate] DateTime; SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE As_Of_Date = [@MyDate];")
    qdf.Parameters("[@MyDate]").Value = Date()

Set Me.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: That's a valid alternative. I've never set `Me.RecordSet` to a DAO recordset before, since I've always just used filters for this behavior (I've used ADO recordsets for external databases, so had some experience with that. You might want to replace `.QueryDefs("qryName")` with `.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date = [@MyDate]")` to be more applicable to the question, though, to account for the query not being stored.

Comment: Usually, the parameter definition can be omitted, but inserting it certainly is a good practice, especially if you rely on typecasting